# curL specific data from a webpage

Tags: php, database, curl, libcurl, data-capture

I have no experience with curL , need to find out how I can get weather info from a website and save it to a sql db , I have been able to echo the webpage using curL but thats it, the site is: http://www.weather.bm/forecastpublicextended.asp , I just want to capture the temperature from their.. another problem my intranet webserver is in a locked down enviroment meaning it has no ie access does curl execute client side, I assume it does any help will be appreciated as I am hitting my head against wall now.

Comment: Take a look at the [DOM](http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension, if you are familiar with the dom in the browsers you access via javascript that would feel familiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of [`curl`](https://www.php.net/curl) and [`domdocument`](https://www.php.net/domdocument), you would then be able to (A) download the remote page, and (B) parse the dom document based off of selectors / paths.